# how to remove multiple <br> tages in to single <br> tag in java

Tags: java

This is I am writing the code but it is not working. How to write this?

```
data=data.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
data=data.replaceAll("(<br>)+", "<br>");
```

How to work on this is this is very important.

### Input like this:

wefjwefhiwf\n\n\njwfvuwfbw\n\nuioefhcweiuf

### output:

wefjwefhiwf<br>jwfvuwfbw<br>uioefhcweiuf

Comment: please, add an input string with the desired output and the output you receive instead.

Comment: ewfwe\n\nwefwefi\n\nwefnwef this is input

Comment: what output do you expect from this input?

Comment: if you're running on windows, then new line is represented differently

Comment: ewfwe<br>wefwefi<br>wefnwef

Comment: this is exactly the output of your code. Where is the problem?

Comment: i am returning like this return content("cost","\n");

Comment: Add these three things to your question 1) Your input 2) Expected output 3) actual output

Comment: whats wrong? What do you wish ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="wefjwefhiwf\n\n\njwfvuwfbw\n\nuioefhcweiuf";
s=s.trim().replaceAll("\n+","<br>");//+ for multiple occurrences 
System.out.println(s);//prints wefjwefhiwf<br>jwfvuwfbw<br>uioefhcweiuf
```

Comment: what is need of s.trim() ?

Comment: here `trim()` is not needed. @OpenJDK

Comment: i have tried like this but it is not working in browser

Comment: displaying multiple <br> tages

Comment: how to replace multiple words into single word like customSplitcustomSplitcustomSplitcustomSplitcustomSplitcustomSplit into single one customSplit